# Json data generator date and time only

Tags: json, date, datetime, code-generation

I'm trying to generate some Json data using http://beta.json-generator.com/, but I can not figure out how to generate date and time only (instead of datetime)

For example, the following code:

```
[
{
'repeat(5, 10)': {
  _id: '{{objectId()}}',
  date: '{{date()}}',
  date_only: '{{date()}}',  //how can I show here date only
  time_only: '{{date()}}',  //how can I show here time only
  user: {
    first: '{{firstName()}}',
    last: '{{surname()}}'
  },
  phone: '+1 {{phone()}}'
}
}
]
```

Any ideas on how to code the date_only and time_only lines to truncate the datetime?

Also, can the {date} be formatted. For example instead of:

```
"Sat Mar 31 1990 21:01:10 GMT+0000 (UTC)"
```

... something like:

```
"2010-12-13 21:01:10 GMT"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

checkout 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date
hope this one helps u

Comment: I get an error when I try, for example:date_only: '{{Date(1995, 11, 17)}}',  /Error: TypeError: undefined is not a function